# How can I "forward" the entire SwiftUI environment to another view?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

It seems that certain SwiftUI views create new environment contexts, such as `NavigationLink`. None of the environment is available in the new view.

As a workaround, I've been just manually forwarding through environment variables, like this:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var foo: UserStore
    @EnvironmentObject var bar: UserStore

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination:
            SomeOtherView()
                .environmentObject(self.foo)
                .environmentObject(self.bar)
        ) {
            Text("Open View")
        }
    }
}
```

However this seems broken, as it violates the purpose of the environment. Also, it's confusing because it's not clear (or documented?) where these boundaries are and it causes a runtime error when a view depends on a missing `EnvironmentObject`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Similarly, I want to create a wrapper `UIViewControllerRepresentable` that can contain SwiftUI children (via `UIHostingController`) and I would like those children to have access to the environment as well.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm having the same issue - there doesn't seem to be a way to forward the entire environment

Comment: No, I'm hoping its fixed in iOS 14 somehow.

Comment: Now I'm hoping it's fixed in iOS 15 somehow.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've given up on using NavigationView and NavigationLink entirely due to this and many other bugs _shrug_